# Where are the pvalues in the rugarch::multifit() output?

Tags: r, multivariate-time-series, fgarch

I'm using the `rugarch::multifit()` function in R. However, I can't figure out where the p-values are. Indeed, the output only report the coefficients, which is OK but I don't know about their significance.

This is my code :

```
require(pacman)
p_load(quantmod, dplyr, rugarch) #required packages

startDate=as.Date("2023-09-01")
endDate=as.Date(Sys.Date()) #dates

symbol.vec=c("SPY", "^DJI" )
getSymbols(symbol.vec ,from=startDate, to=endDate) #extract data in yahoo finance 
names(DJI)<-c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted")
names(SPY)<-c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted")

zoo_object <- as.zoo(cbind(DJI$Close, SPY$Close))
names(zoo_object)<-c("DJI", "SPY")

returns <- as.zoo(apply(zoo_object , 2, function(x) diff(log(x) , lag=1))) #calculate returns
annualized_ret <- returns * sqrt(252) #calculate annualized returns

###univariate GARCH specifications
spec<-ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="eGARCH",
                                     garchOrder=c(1,1)), 
                 mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0), include.mean=T), 
                 distribution.model="sstd")

### fit to data with multispec and multifit
mspec = multispec( replicate(spec, n = 2) )
fitlist = multifit(multispec = mspec, data = annualized_ret)
```

Now, the output in fitlist looks like this :

```
*----------------------------*
*     GARCH Multi-Fit        *
*----------------------------*
No. Assets :2
GARCH Multi-Spec Type : Equal
GARCH Model Spec
--------------------------
Model : eGARCH
Exogenous Regressors in variance equation: none

Mean Equation :
Include Mean :  1
AR(FI)MA Model : (0,d,0)
GARCH-in-Mean :  FALSE
Exogenous Regressors in mean equation: none
Conditional Distribution:  sstd 

GARCH Model Fit
--------------------------
Optimal Parameters:
              DJI      SPY
mu        0.02781  0.01743
omega    -0.42092 -0.52861
alpha1   -0.06894 -0.20948
beta1     0.91263  0.87563
gamma1   -0.45938 -0.55203
skew      1.12497  0.91316
shape     5.94730  4.31638
Log-Lik 112.11050 88.24099
```

Where can I see the p-values for each variable ? Also, is there a way to create a table with both the coefficients ***and*** the pvalues ?