# Errors in rugarch multifit output

Tags: r, volatility

I've been conducting some tests in the R package `rugarch`, and particularly the `multispec()/multifit()` functions. I found some errors in the output of these functions, and I can't figure out why (maybe it's my fault !). Here I don't provide directly reproducible example as the errors are only in the output and not really in the type of data, but I can if needed.

I've fitted a GARCH model to several series with very basic commands, and I basically obtain an univariate GARCH model applied to several series. The command is like that :

```
spec<-ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="eGARCH",
                                     garchOrder=c(1,1), external.regressors=as.matrix(ext)), 
                 mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0), include.mean=T), 
                   distribution.model="sstd")


fit<-ugarchfit(spec, returns1[,1) #only for one series
mspec = multispec( replicate(spec, n = 3) )
fitlist = multifit(multispec = mspec, data = returns[,1:3]) #applied on three series
```

Two problems arise here.

***1 - Results are different while the model is the same***

The coefficients are different for the common series in `fit` and `fitlist`, which can't be the case. In `fit`, I obtain these coefficients:

```
       Estimate  
mu      0.084729    
omega   0.065768    
alpha1 -0.410989    
beta1   0.868151    
gamma1 -2.195101    
vxreg1 -0.052592    
skew    1.045669   
shape   2.054839
```

and in `fitlist`, for the first column I obtain these coefficients :

```
Optimal Parameters:
          Estimate
mu        0.00321     
omega    -2.14288  
alpha1    1.90533   
beta1     0.28411   
gamma1    0.87675  
vxreg1    0.03007  
skew      1.01694   
shape     2.01000
```

***2 - Results in output are different from the results displayed***

When I get in the fitted GARCH object with `View(fitlist)`
[View(fitlist)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2iKC.png).
However, when I type `fitlist@fit[[1]]@fit[["coef"]]` which is supposed to extract these coefficients, I obtain this :

```
mu               omega       alpha1        beta1       gamma1       vxreg1         skew 
 0.003210617  -2.142881027  1.905325760  0.284106931  0.876747643  0.030068255  1.016941148 
       shape 
 2.010000000
```

which does not correspond to the results in the screenshot. Is it normal ? Do I miss something ?

If anyone has a potential answer I'll be happy to hear it !

Comment: Oh and also, I've another related question : the ```fitlist``` command don't display the p-values and I can't find them. Again, if you have an idea of where they are, I've posted the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78027449/where-are-the-pvalues-in-the-rugarchmultifit-output (with a reproducible example !)